# How to set environment variable in OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

I want to add a path variable to the directory `~/bin`

How should I do it in OS X Lion?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question really shouldn't be that hard to find.

#### For your shell

Just add

```
export PATH=/Users/your-user/bin:$PATH
```

in one of the shell configuration files, e.g. `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` if you don't have the former one.

#### For all users

You can also set paths system-wide in the following folder:

```
/etc/paths.d
```

By creating a file, e.g. naming it `custom`, then adding one line per path you want to add, e.g.

```
/Users/your-user/bin
```

That obviously doesn't make a lot of sense if these binaries belong to you.

#### For the graphical environment

Create the following file:

```
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

Add variables to this preference list like so:

[image]